# Creating a service around Restangular in AngularJS is not returning array

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am new to AngularJS and Restangular.  But being a good citizen I thought I would try to create some services.

While this works and I get an array back populating a drop down list:

```
Restangular.all('/ta/tas').getList().then(function(tas) {
                $scope.therapyAreas = tas;           
             });
```

But when I create a service, and then inject the service into the controller I get nothing back:

```
.controller('prGPTCtrl',['$scope', 'prTAService', 'Restangular', function($scope, prTAService, Restangular) {

            $scope.prGpts = {};
            $scope.therapyAreas = {};


            Restangular.setBaseUrl('resources/pr');         

            $scope.therapyAreas = prTAService.prTAList();
```

Service:

```
prServices.factory('prTAService', ['Restangular', '$q', function prTAService(Restangular, $q) {
    return {        
             prTAList : function(therapyAreas) {
                 var therapyAreas = {};
                 Restangular.setBaseUrl('resources/pr');
                 Restangular.all('/ta/tas').getList().then(function(tas) {
                    therapyAreas = tas; 
                    return therapyAreas;
                 }
                );              
             }
    };  
}]);
```

I see it being called in Chrome Debugger...I suspect it is related to promises (which I don't really "get").

Update:

This works as a service:

```
prServices.factory('prTAService', ['Restangular', '$q', function prTAService(Restangular, $q) {
    return {        
             prTAList : function(therapyAreas) {                 
                 Restangular.setBaseUrl('resources/pr');
                 return Restangular.all('/ta/tas').getList();
             }
    };  
}]);
```

And this works when calling it, not sure what I am gaining here!

```
prTAService.prTAList().then(function(tas) {
                $scope.therapyAreas = tas;
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service needs to return the promise and the controller will handle the return because this is asynchronous. You are doing it right in the last part there:

```
prTAService.prTAList().then(function(tas) {
                $scope.therapyAreas = tas;
            });
```

Comment: OK, thanks...need to get my head round promises, not used to asynchronous programming.

Comment: No worries, yes it is a little confusing at first.

Comment: feels like I need to put all my controller logic in a then clause as thats the only place I can be sure I have my stuff.